# css html change panel on hover

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
.panel-default:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Panel Footer</h2>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/frontdoor/creative/Embed/hero_dog_482206371.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a `panel` like this and I want `overlay` when I `hover` to it. 
Here I am using `background-color:black` to make the background `black`.

But the problem is on `hover` black color only appears at `panel-body` while I am using at `panel-default`

How can I make a `overlay` on `hover` on `panel`

Comment: Please change the title. Title not match to your real issue

Comment: And your code working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/5mr6nndL/

Comment: @ketan sorry about the title

Comment: the background is black below image.. I want the background over image too..

Answer (score 0):

The background color is falling behind the image, since the image is a replaced element. Add another style rule to hide the image on hover:

```
.panel-default:hover img{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8btcypv6/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an absolutely placed overlay element, though @symlink's answer is much shorter.

```css
.panel-default {
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
.panel-default:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Panel Footer</h2>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/frontdoor/creative/Embed/hero_dog_482206371.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `filter` property for `image`:

```
img {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
  -moz-filter: opacity(1);
  filter: opacity(1);
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(0);
  -moz-filter: opacity(0);
  filter: opacity(0);
}
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/5mr6nndL/1/)